# Trying to call a global variable into a google maps function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

```
,,,<script>


var eventlong;
var eventlat;

$('#eventreg').on('show.bs.modal', 


                 function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var eventtitle = button.data('eventtitle')
  var eventdate = button.data('eventdate')
  var eventtime = button.data('eventtime')
  var eventtype = button.data('eventtype')
  var eventlong = button.data('eventlong')
  var eventlat  = button.data('eventlat')


  modal.find('#eventtitle').text(eventtitle)
 modal.find('#eventtype').text(eventtype)

})

    </script>
 <script>

      function initMap() {
          var latm = eventlat;
      var lngm = eventlong;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 'latm',lng: 'lngm'},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>   </script>
,,,
```

Hi in the above code i am using bootstrap and a data-* to pre populate variables for presentation in a modal. Being the guy that always wants to take it one step further. I declared two variables as global '''eventlong''' and'''' eventlat''' (they are numeric) Long and Lat values that i am trying to pull into a google maps API call. I removed my api key to protect the innocent. 
But i can't seem to get it. any guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not obvious what you're asking, but this doesn't look right: `{lat: 'latm',lng: 'lngm'}`, those values are literal strings. To use the variables instead, drop the quotes: `{lat: latm,lng: lngm}`

Comment: where exactly you're not able to get them? And also, you don't need to use var the second time you assign a value them since they were declared at the top